# NCrunch can't find relative file path

Tags: ncrunch

My app.config has a reference to a master.config.

When NCrunch runs the tests it can't locate the master.config file as they run from a different directory; as such the test window always shows red and somewhat defeats the purpose of NCrunch.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried editing the NCrunch configuration for the project and including the master.config within the "Additional files to include" option?

Comment: @IanNelson That's the fix!  thanks.

Comment: Really?! I'm gonna add it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the NCrunch configuration for the project and include the `master.config` within the "Additional files to include" option.